# Login Problem on Cloud Server

Tags: control-panel, error-message, login

i'm developing on a dedicated root server and all works fine. 
The whole installation (database and all files except `/craft/storage`) is then pushed to an git repository and will be deployed to the production server from there.

The production server is a cloud server and i can not log in the CP on this server. I can load the admin page, but if i try to login, nothing happens.
The XHR-Request gives back following error:

```
Server Error
session_regenerate_id(): Session object destruction failed
```

I found this https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/2376 but i think a custom fix to the yii framework is not the right solution for me.

Any suggestions?

thanks and brgrds 
Stephan

Comment: If you're on the latest version of Craft, then the fix you linked to is already in place. Does your cloud based service allow file system write access?

Comment: Hi Brad, sounds good, i didn't make the last update yet. Due to security issues i can't make the update on the production server (no wirte perrmissions to the app directory). Just to be sure, is there any problem if i update the development server and then transfer the changes via git to the production server?

Comment: Nope... that's a pretty common workflow.

Comment: Sounds like more of a server issue than craft issue.

Comment: After the update everything works fine. Thank you